# Invoking methods on objects in java

Tags: java

Here's the relevant part of the Dice class:

```
import java.util.*;
class Dice 
{ 
    String name ; 
    int x ; 
    int[] sum ;
```

...

```
public Dice (String name) 
    { 
        this.name = name ; 
        this.x = 0 ; 
        this.sum = new int[7] ; 
    }
```

...

```
public void roll () 
    {
        this.x = randNum(1, this.sum.length) ; 
        this.sum[x] ++ ;
    }
```

I am invoking this method in a separate class named `Risk`

```
class Risk 
{
```

Heres the first line of the method:

```
public static void IdiceRoll (Dice o)
```

So this method takes a dice that already exists as a paramater so theres no need to create a new dice inside it.

Finaly here is how i'm trying to invoke `roll` on `o`:

```
o.Dice.roll () ;
```

Comment: Note that the (free) Sun documentation includes several tutorials, which are very useful for learning stuff like this.  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in this post?

Comment: @luis.espinal There used to be, apparently it was lost in an edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your other class, in some method, you need to get an instance of the class you're trying to use.  You need an import statement if you're in another package.

Then it's simple:

```
// Create an instance of class Dice named dice
Dice dice = new Dice();

// call the method on the instance you just created
dice.roll();
```

Also, refer to [Sun's documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/index.html) and try examples to get your feet under you.

Revision to match your changes:

```
public class Risk
{
   public static void IdiceRoll(Dice o)
   {
      o.roll();
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear in the question. The method in whcih i am invoking this method takes a Dice named o as a paramater so the dice doesn't need to be created. Also in the dice.roll doesn't Dice need to be capitalized?

Comment: @David I updated to show the situation you described.  No, you have to use the *variable name* when calling methods, not the *class* name, which is **Dice**.  The only time this isn't true is if the method you are calling is a *static* method, but you don't need to worry about that right now.

Comment: @David, what is given here is correct. You do not reference the class name (the capitalized form `Dice`) when you attempt to call the object method (`o.roll()` if the parameter is defined as `Dice o`; or dice.roll() if the variable is locally defined as Jonathon has it). You would use the class name to call the method if it is `static`.

Comment: Ok. i thought it aplied to non-static methods becuase i've alwayse had to use the class name when invoking static methods in classes in whcih their not defined. Why don't you have to do this for methods that arn't static?

Comment: @David, I will write a longer answer.

Comment: @David Static methods are associated with the *class itself*, not an *instance* of the class, and thus you use the *class* name when invoking the static method.  Normal methods are associated with *instances* of the class, so you must *qualify* the call with a variable.  Methods generally change the *state* (for example, fields) of an object, and variables are the containers that hold both *state* and *behavior* (or methods).

Answer (score 3):

It appears from your comment responses that you may not understand the difference between `static` and non-static methods.

To invoke a static method, you use the class and method name. Let's take a slightly modified example:

```
public class Dice {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private int sides;

    protected Dice(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    public static Dice create(int sides) {
        return new Dice(sides);
    }

    public int roll() {
        synchronized(RANDOM) {
            return RANDOM.nextInt(sides) + 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I can create a new `Dice` using the static factory method using the `static` method call form (class name + method name):

```
Dice d = Dice.create(6);
```

But for normal methods you call them in relation to an instantiated object because they may operate on data stored with that object. In this case, I have created an object that is held in the reference variable `d` and this object contains the number of sides that it should generate a number for. To call it, use:

```
int value = d.roll();
```

There are many advantages to using normal methods over static ones. Do not overuse `static` methods. Static methods are not inherited and are not part of an object - they are just considered part of the class. This is why you call static methods using the class name (though Java does unfortunately allow the object.method usage as well but a good IDE will warn you about that). There is no related memory state. However, an object itself also has memory state and there may be many different instances of the class with different values. Here we could create different sided dice:

```
Dice six = Dice.create(6);
Dice twenty = Dice.create(20);

// Use the dice for a 1D6 + 1D20 roll.
int value = six.roll() + twenty.roll();
```

In this example, I've called the `roll` method on two different object instances. Using `Dice.roll()` will not work since the roll method must be called in relation to the instance so it knows how many sides (in this case) to do the roll for.

More advance topic: That static method is a factory and could create sub-classes that have different features/randomness based on the number of sides. For example, later I could create a special sub-class of Dice called TrickDice and any time someone asked for a 5 sided dice they get one of those simply by changing the `create` method:

```
public static Dice create(int sides) {
    if (sides == 5)
        return new TrickDice(5);
    else
        return new Dice(sides);
}
```

This does not change how it is called...

```
Dice d = Dice.create(5); // This really is a TrickDice
```

This is one of the valid usages of a `static` method. Again, though do not overuse static methods, try to use normal methods as much as possible as you are learning the language.

**EDIT**: I noticed in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641262/will-this-ever-result-in-a-stack-overflow-error) that you use this method signature:

```
public static void printDice (Dice Dice)
```

Here you have named the class and variable using the same letter case. I address this here in this question because this may help you with some of the confusion you expressed here. You should be careful about the names you use for your classes and variables. Strangely, Java actually accepts this syntax. The first `Dice` is the class name (type) and the second `Dice` is the parameter name. Instead, you should use lower case letters for the variable/parameter name, so it should look like this:

```
public static void printDice (Dice dice)
```

Then it will be more clear within the method when you are using an object reference (`dice`) or the class name (`Dice`).

Also, this print method probably should be a method on the `Dice` class. With OOP you should think of asking the object to print itself. This allows different sub-classes to provide different ways to print themselves without trying to put all the logic in a single method. This is an example of overusing a static method which diminishes the value and flexibility of your classes.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the object, then call the method:

```
Dice redSparklyPair = new Dice();
redSparklyPair.roll();
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.  If you have an object of type `Dice`, you can just do

```
public class NotDice {
  // ...
  public int method() {
    Dice dice = new Dice();
    dice.roll();
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

If you're in a subclass of `Dice`, then you can call the superclass method with the `super` keyword:

```
public class WeightedDice extends Dice {
  // ...
  public void roll() {
    // ...
    super.roll();
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

`super` is just like `this`, except that it looks one level up the class hierarchy.  As far as I know, there's no way to call a *specific* superclass's method; you can only look one level up.  Nevertheless, that's usually sufficient.

Comment: The class in whcih i am invoking roll is a diferent class from the one in which it is defined see edit. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

With your latest question update you just need to say `o.roll();`

If that doesn't work then double-check that the `roll()` method is *public* and **not** *private*.

Comment: i only have to do o.roll even though roll is defined in a diferent class form the one in which i am invoking it?

Comment: Yeah. Because you are telling the instance `o` to `roll()` itself. It is a Dice so it knows that it has to do the `roll()` defined in the Dice class.

Comment: To elaborate: a Dice knows how to do every method you define in the Dice class. So a Dice instance knows how to roll(). As part of that, it can't do *anything* other than those methods in the Dice class (and any of Dice's superclasses). So you don't need to tell it to use the `roll()` from the Dice class because that is the only `roll()` it could do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an *instance* of the `Dice` class and then invoke it.

Suppose you have a `Game`  class:

```
class Risk {
    public static void IdiceRoll (Dice o) {
       // You have to roll the dice
       //  The dice already exist, you just... roll it!!
       o.roll();
       // And that's it
    }
 }
```

`Dice` is the name of the class, the class is just like a template or a  blueprint. It defined things ( like variables and methods ).

To use a class you usually create **object** from it.  In this case you can name your object whatever you want ( in this case it is named `o`)

So when you declare:

```
Dice o
```

You're saying. There is a variable named `o` of type `Dice` then the compiler know what attributes and what method can be invoked from that object.

As you saw, to invoke a method on an object you use the `.` and the name of the method followed by its parameters ( if any )

```
 o.roll();
```

That's how **instance** ( non-static )  methods work

**static** ( class methods officially ) methods in the other hand, operate in the class itself, that's why they don't need an instance.

```
So, it is possible to invoke them directly:

 Risk.IdiceRoll( aDiceInstance );
```

I think you should really take a moment to read this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/concepts/  and understand how Java implements those concepts.

Comment: The method in which i am trying to invoke roll takes a dice as a paramater so i don't need to create an instance of Dice first. Sorry for the confusion. please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dice dice = new Dice();
dice.roll;
```

Comment: the method roll is in a diferent class form the one in whcih i'm doing this in though. see edit.

Comment: -1 For people learning a language and asking about syntax (like the asker is here) having sytax errors in answers can be more harm than good.

Comment: my mistake ! been using ruby lately.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get a reference to the instance of the object then invoke roll()

```
Dice dice = new Dice();
dice.roll();
```

Comment: The class in whcih i am invoking roll is a diferent class from the one in which it is defined see edit.